# Use Array.filter to return values for a set number of items

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-filter

I currently have a function that returns a value for each item in my array, up to a maximum number. It looks like this

```
const myArray = [
    { url: "example.com/1", other: "foo" },
    { url: "example.com/sdf", other: "foo"  },
    { url: "example.com/blue", other: "foo"  },
    { url: "example.com/foo", other: "foo"  },
    { url: "example.com/123", other: "foo"  },
];

function getNumberOfUrls(data, num) {
  const newArray = [];

  data?.forEach(function (datum) {
    if (newArray.length < num) {
      newArray.push(datum.url);
    }
  });

  return newArray;
}

// Output
//["example.com/1", "example.com/sdf", "example.com/blue"]
```

It simply returns the `url` for each object in the array until it hits the limit provided. It works fine, but I was trying to explore if there is a more suitable Array function I should be using.

I know `Array.filter` creates a new array based on whether the iterated item passes a particular condition, but I wondered if it could be used to check whether something else passes the condition - in this case the parent array.

```
function getNumberOfUrls(data, num) {
  return data.filter(datum => /* return url until we hit .length === num in data? */ )
};
```

How can I make this work or is there a better-suited Array method to achieve this?

**ETA: the original example array didn't paint the full picture. I've now added more data to show the issue. I don't want to return an array with just the first three objects, I want to just return the `url` value from the first three objects.**

Comment: `forEach` will always run over the entire array it is called on, use a standard `for` or `for...of` to exit early, or simply [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). `data.slice(0, num).map(datum => datum.url)`

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly now. It's a short and sweet syntax, and gives the right result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortest way to do this is using `Array.slice`:

```js
const myArray = [
  { url: "example.com/1" },
  { url: "example.com/sdf" },
  { url: "example.com/blue" },
  { url: "example.com/foo" },
  { url: "example.com/123" },
]

const limit = 3
const shorterArray = myArray.slice(0, limit).map(item => item.url)

console.log(shorterArray)
```

*I removed my other code, as it was inefficient, and should not be used.*

Comment: This doesn't save anything, filter still iterates the whole array. A slice of the limit length, or early exited for loop is more appropriate.

Comment: That's a fair point, I just updated my answer. I got caught up on OP's use of the word filter in his question, and completely blanked on Array.slice.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian - a combo of `.slice()` and `.map()` definitely gives the quickest result

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be use Array.from() and it's internal mapper

```js
const myArray = [
    { url: "example.com/1" },
    { url: "example.com/sdf" },
    { url: "example.com/blue" },
    { url: "example.com/foo" },
    { url: "example.com/123" },
];

function getNumberOfUrls(data, num) {
  return Array.from({length:num}, (v,i) => data[i].url)
}

console.log(getNumberOfUrls(myArray, 3))
```

Answer (score -1):

Given a JavaScript array, how do you get just the first X items of it?

Use the built-in slice() method that comes with each array instance:
(Note that the original array is not modified in this operation.)

```js
const myArray = [
{ url: "example.com/1", other: "foo" },
{ url: "example.com/sdf", other: "foo"  },
{ url: "example.com/blue", other: "foo"  },
{ url: "example.com/foo", other: "foo"  },
{ url: "example.com/123", other: "foo"  },
];

const limit = 3 //get the first 3 items

const newArray = myArray.slice(0,limit).map( (item) => {return {url:item.url} })
console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: While this is nice and simple, I realised my example wasn't telling the full story. I don't wish to return the full first 3 objects, I only want the `url` value from each. I've updated my example to show there is additional data. Using `.slice()` would return the first three objects, I'd still have to iterate over them to get just the `url` value

Comment: I adjusted the answer to your update I hope this will help

Comment: I've imporved the answer to combine map and slice and also return the whole key:object {url:'value'} instead of just the url

Answer (score -1):

You could simply set the length of the newly mapped array

**Edit**: The `.map()` is used as the final array is different to the starting array (just urls in final as opposed to objects in starting array)

```js
const myArray = [
    { url: "example.com/1" },
    { url: "example.com/sdf" },
    { url: "example.com/blue" },
    { url: "example.com/foo" },
    { url: "example.com/123" },
];

function getNumberOfUrls(data, num) {
  
  let newArray = data.map(el => el.url);
  newArray.length = num;

  return newArray;
}

console.log(getNumberOfUrls(myArray, 3))
```

Comment: Why iterate the entire array if you only need the first n elements?

Comment: Check the map, the final array is different to the starting array. The OP doesn't want an array of objects.

Comment: That isn't the issue, the point is there is no reason to map over the entire passed array, only the first `num` elements.

Comment: @pilchard Ah I get what you mean - yeah, I agree could simply reverse the order of events. Good shout.